# Python: Make Class Itself Callable

Tags: python, class

My question might seem stupid. But, I wish to know if there is a way in Python to make a Class itself callable. No I'm not talking about making a Class Instance callable. I'm talking about something like this:

```py
class Foo:
    def __call__(value):
        return do_something_with(value)
    #note I didn't use self because I want the class itself to be callable, not an instance of it

a = Foo(some_random_value)
```

But this doesn't seem to work. So, is there any way to do it or is it impossible to do in Python?

Comment: A class is *already* callable. You call it and it returns instances. If you *were* able  override this, how would you make an instance? If you don't need instances, maybe a class is the wrong tool.

Comment: What's your use-case? Why not use the ``__init__`` method? Or why not use a function instead of a class? Functions are also objects and can be assigned attributes if that matters.

Comment: How would you differentiate between `Foo()` and `Foo()` then? (One makes an instance, the other "calls" it…)

Comment: @MikeScotty How would I use the init method to do it? I mean, init creates an instance without returning a value, doesn't it?

Comment: If you want to "call" `Foo()` without it resulting in an instance of `Foo`, why use a class in the first place? Use a function instead.

Comment: @deceze I don't need the former, I want a way to disable the former [possibly override the init method in such a way that it doesn't create an instance and returns a value instead]

Comment: It does return a value - it returns the instance. Maybe you're looking for the ``@staticmethod`` or ``@classmethod`` decorator if you want to call a class method w/o creating an instance.

Comment: @deceze I can't do that since there are Class Methods [not Instance Methods] associated with that Class. But now that I think of it I could use a function inside a function

Comment: Why not have a method inside class and call that method using instance of the class?

Comment: @Arnil you keep mentioning why you can't do things, but you're avoiding the question of *why* you need to do this with a class. What is your use case?

Comment: FWIW: You can define `def __new__(cls):` and do all sorts of mischief — it will be called when you call your class —  but that's a *terrible* idea.

Comment: @MarkMeyer I'm passing a class as a parameter to a function which uses other Class Methods present inside the class, and needs to use the Class itself as a function. I could work around that but I think being able to make the class callable would be neat. So what I want to know is whether it is possible or not

Comment: A classes "callable" is basically `__new__`. But as mentioned above, if you return anything but an instance of `Foo` from `Foo.__new__`, that's… *unexpected* at least.

Comment: You're saying you want to make the *class* callable (which is already callable). Do you mean that you want to make the *instance* callable instead?

Comment: By your stated requirements, defining a function called `Foo` would suffice.

Comment: @BlueRineS I already said that that's not the case

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer Normally it would but my use case is a bit different, plus I'm mostly curious actually

Comment: *"I'm passing a class as a parameter to a function which uses other Class Methods present inside the class, and needs to use the Class itself as a function."* – That functions seems to have weird expectations then. It's unusual to expect something to be a class which does not return an instance of itself when called.

Comment: @deceze Well I think I fixed the problem by using nested functions instead, need to try running it though

Comment: @Arnil I would appreciate it very much if you posted some example code of what your expected results is and what you've tried so far. That would make us understand your expectations much much better, and moreover you will probably gain some upvotes from it :)

Comment: @Arnil We have literally no idea what to tell you. "my use case is different and I am curious" is not a very explicit set of requirements.

Answer (score 0):

As explained above, and for probably all use cases, this is a very bad idea, don't do it! (puppies will die!)

```
class Foo:
    def __new__(self, value):
        return Foo.__call__(value)
    @classmethod
    def __call__(cls, value):
        return f'processed {value}'

print(Foo(42))
```

**output:**

```
processed 42
```